# Only part of my image links. Why?

Tags: html, wordpress, image, hyperlink

Only the top bit of my image links through to YouTube, I need the whole image to do so. Any idea why not? Here's my code:

```html
<p style="margin-top: 5px;">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">
    <img class="alignleft wp-image-557" src="http://valid image url" alt="" width="196" height="165" />
  </a>
<p style="margin-top: 5px;">
```

Comment: The code is: < p style="margin-top: 5px;"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank"><img class="alignleft wp-image-557" src="http://validurl" alt="" width="196" height="165" /></a>
<p style="margin-top: 5px;">

Comment: Did the question make sense?